# Why does two-way binding not work in some situations?

Tags: angularjs

Consider this HTML

```
...
<label>Weight:
    <input type="text" ng-model="weight">
</label><br>
<label>Height:
    <input type="text" ng-model="height">
</label><br>
<label>
    BMI: {{bmi}}
</label>
...
```

and this JavaScript

```
...
$scope.bmi = +$scope.weight / +$scope.height * +$scope.height;
...
```

If I give values to the weight and height input fields in the browser, why doesn't the BMI field get updated? Obviously when the controller loads for the first time, the $scope.weight and $scope.height values are empty. But once they get values from the view, why doesn't $scope.bmi use these new values? I have found numerous solutions for this problem (by using $watch or calling a function that updates the bmi value), but could somebody explain WHY the code above does not work?

Comment: If you look at your problem in this way, whenever you write `{{someVariable}}` angular creates a watcher for you. In your current logic angular have not created those watchers that you can write manually to make your current code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because $scope.bmi is calculated for one time only when controller loads. you will have to make bmi property to be computable or dependable to calculate everytime you change the value of height and weight

See the demo code [here](http://goo.gl/YCeHW1) to see how can we make dependent properties in angularjs

Answer (score 0):

It's because your bmi here is an affectation. This is set the 1st time you call the controller and never change. Because your var is just a primitive value,i t's not a binding, just a value. A binding could work with a function store on factory for example.

With a function you can update the value.

```
<label>Weight:
    <input type="text" ng-change="updateBMI()" ng-model="weight">
</label><br>
<label>Height:
    <input type="text" ng-change="updateBMI()" ng-model="height">
</label><br>
<label>
    BMI: {{bmi}}
</label>
```

And then in your controller you will have the update function :

```
$scope.updateBMI = function(){
  $scope.bmi = +$scope.weight / +$scope.height * +$scope.height;
}
```